# .NET RegexParseException negation character

Tags: c#, .net, regex

## Correct

This regex:

> (.+)("and" )+([0-9]+)( is proudly)(.+)

In this text:

> RegExr was created by gskinner.com, "and" 6455464 is proudly hosted by
> Media 6464888 Temple.
> Edit the Expression & Text to see matches. Roll over matches or the expression for details. PCRE & JavaScript flavors of RegEx are
> supported. Validate your expression with Tests mode.

Gives me by code successful result.

Code:

```
var text = @"RegExr was created by gskinner.com, ""and"" 6455464 is proudly hosted by Media 6464888 Temple.

Edit the Expression & Text to see matches. Roll over matches or the expression for details. PCRE & JavaScript flavors of RegEx are supported. Validate your expression with Tests mode.";

Regex r = new Regex(
    @"(.+)(""and"" )+([0-9]+)( is proudly)(.+)", 
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Match m = r.Match(text);
```

Code result:

[image]

regexr.com result:

[image]

## Error

If I change the regex to:

> ([^]+)("and" )+([0-9]+)( is proudly)([^]+)

regexr.com result is correct and works:

[image]

But if I put it in code, like this:

```
var text = @"RegExr was created by gskinner.com, ""and"" 6455464 is proudly hosted by Media 6464888 Temple.

Edit the Expression & Text to see matches. Roll over matches or the expression for details. PCRE & JavaScript flavors of RegEx are supported. Validate your expression with Tests mode.";

Regex r = new Regex(
    @"([^]+)(""and"" )+([0-9]+)( is proudly)([^]+)", 
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Match m = r.Match(text);
```

I have this exception:

> System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexParseException: 'Invalid pattern
> '([^]+)("and" )+([0-9]+)( is proudly)([^]+)' at offset 42.
> Unterminated [] set.'

So questions are:

- Why regex pattern works in regexr.com and not in code?
- How to solve it?

Comment: `[^]` is only ECMAScript compliant. In .NET regex just use `.` with the `RegexOptions.Singleline` option (or the inline `(?s)` one).

Comment: I will try it and tell you, thanks